# Amazon Cloudwatch Logs, parse datetime result of a function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

In our logs, we get uptime as a millisecond and I am trying to format it using the AWS CloudWatch query. But I found out that it is not possible to parse the result of some function, only field values itself can be used. Example:

```
fields 
  req.stats.uptime, 
  fromMillis(req.stats.uptime) as tstamp, 
  "1970-01-03T22:53:01.000+01:00" as tz
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 1
| fields @timestamp
| parse tstamp "T*:*:*." as H, M, S
| filter req.url like /\/healthcheck/ and ispresent(req.stats.uptime)
```

if i parse `"tstamp" - i` get nothing, empty HMS, but if i parse `"tz"`, i get proper values back..

does someone know how to avoid this problem? unfortunately, I don't see formating available in AWS CloudWatch queries possible and at the moment I think, the best way could be to format on the service side and put already formatted into logs. But maybe someone knows a better solution?

Regards in advise